# Email div content of images with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I'm having a problem trying to email some content of a div through php. I have a multistep form that takes various input types in stages to personalise a piece of jewellery. One of these steps in the multistep form offers an engraving service on a jewellery piece. 
I want the customer to click on a selection of characters, symbols and add those images to another div that creates their message. I can't seem to send the div contents to the PHP page. I also want to be able to email this data so our jeweller can read it.

This is my markup:

```
 <form action="contact.php" method="post"  class="ajax"> 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                     <div style="text-align: center;" class="col-md-12 header">
                        <img src="images/layoutoptions.jpg" alt="kryptos layout options in diagrams">
                        <br>
                        <h3>Click to add a character and build your message. Up to 70 characters.</h3>
                        <p>Layout options include:   Full message– (we use a symbol to signify the start and end), Split message – (symbols can separate sections), Split message – rotate to read (each element is separated by symbols) or  Short message (can be started and finished with a symbol).</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div class="row">
                    <div id="characters" class="col-md-6">
                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/A-acorn.jpg">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/B-butterfly.jpg">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/C-cross.jpg">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/D-diamonds.jpg">
                      </span>
                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/E-eternal.jpg">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/F-feet.jpg">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/G-flower.jpg">
                      </span>

                    </div>

                    <div id="FrontFace" name="frontface" class="col-md-6"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <input class="button" type="BUTTON" id="btn2" value="Undo">
                      <input class="button" type="BUTTON" id="btn3" value="Clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h2 id="textarea_feedback"> 70 characters remaining</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="errors" class="col-md-6"></div>
                </div> 

                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
    <button type="submit" data-type="submit" class="btn btn-primary msf-nav-button">Submit</button>
```

This is the Jquery:

```
         $(function (){

      var text_max = 70; 

      var source = null;

      var iCnt = 0;

      var text_remaining = 70;


     //Click Image to add to div Frontface
     $('img').click(function(){
      if (iCnt <= 70) {

          source = $(this).attr("src");

          iCnt = iCnt + 1;
          $("#errors").empty();
          $("#FrontFace").append('<span class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ><img alt="faller-kryptos-engraving" width="26" height="auto" src="' + source + '" /></span>');

          text_remaining = text_max - iCnt;

          $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
         }
         else {
          $("#errors").append('<label>Reached the limit</label><br>'); 
         }


      });

      // REMOVE ONE ELEMENT PER CLICK.
      $('#btn2').click(function() {
          if (iCnt != 0) { 

            $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); 

            iCnt = iCnt - 1; 

            text_remaining = text_max - iCnt;

            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining'); 

          }

          if (iCnt == 0) { 
              $("#errors").append('<label>Please add characters.</label><br>'); 
          }
      });

       $("#btn3").click(function(){

          $("#FrontFace").empty();

          $("#errors").empty();

          if (iCnt != 0) {
            iCnt = 0;
            text_remaining = 70;
            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
          }
      });


    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            method = that.attr('method'),
            data ={};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
          var that = $(this),
              name = that.attr('name'),
              value = that.val();

          data[name] = value;
        });

      console.log(data);  


      return false;

    });



  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the jquery needs optimised yet as I've grab a demo of a mutlistep form online and dropped everything in.

p

Comment: Please provide a minified simple example of your problem. this wall-o-code is way to much.

Comment: Apologies, I've trimmed the fat.

Comment: thanks for that but I know the div cant be sent in the form that's why I was trying to loop through the elements with the name attribute and get their value, but I think the problem is that I cant set a value for a div and need to get the div data or contents and assign that to a varaible or something i just dont know how.

Comment: You are not submitting any data because your loop is looking for `name` attribute, which is only present on `#FrontFace` element. So you are just adding `undefined` values (span doesn't have a value) to your data array at `undefined` index

Comment: Is there a way to get the data of the found elements with the name attribute instead of the value?

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting any data because your loop is looking for `name` attribute, which is only present on `#FrontFace` element. So you are just adding `undefined` values (span doesn't have a value) to your data array at `undefined` index.
You should edit your HTML as follows (notice the `<img>` tag only)

```
 <form action="contact.php" method="post"  class="ajax"> 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                     <div style="text-align: center;" class="col-md-12 header">
                        <img src="images/layoutoptions.jpg" alt="kryptos layout options in diagrams">
                        <br>
                        <h3>Click to add a character and build your message. Up to 70 characters.</h3>
                        <p>Layout options include:   Full message– (we use a symbol to signify the start and end), Split message – (symbols can separate sections), Split message – rotate to read (each element is separated by symbols) or  Short message (can be started and finished with a symbol).</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div class="row">
                    <div id="characters" class="col-md-6">
                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/A-acorn.jpg" data-type="A-acorn">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/B-butterfly.jpg" data-type="B-butterfly">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/C-cross.jpg" data-type="C-cross">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/D-diamonds.jpg" data-type="D-diamonds">
                      </span>
                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/E-eternal.jpg" data-type="E-eternal">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/F-feet.jpg" data-type="F-feet">
                      </span>

                      <span>
                        <img width="30" src="http://www.madebyfaller.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/G-flower.jpg" data-type="G-flower">
                      </span>

                    </div>

                    <div id="FrontFace" name="frontface" class="col-md-6"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <input class="button" type="BUTTON" id="btn2" value="Undo">
                      <input class="button" type="BUTTON" id="btn3" value="Clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h2 id="textarea_feedback"> 70 characters remaining</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="errors" class="col-md-6"></div>
                </div> 

                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
    <button type="submit" data-type="submit" class="btn btn-primary msf-nav-button">Submit</button>
```

And your jQuery accordingly. I don't know what you are trying to get as `value` and what as `name` so I will just push items into an array. The code works, but you should edit it according to your needs.

```
$(function() {

    var text_max = 70;
    //var source = null; this should not be global
    var iCnt = 0;
    var text_remaining = 70;


    //Click Image to add to div Frontface
    $('img').click(function() {
        if (iCnt <= 70) {

            var source = $(this).attr("src");
            var type = $(this).data('type');
            iCnt = iCnt + 1;
            $("#errors").empty();
            $("#FrontFace").append('<span class="input" id="tb' + iCnt + '" data-type="' + type + '" ><img alt="faller-kryptos-engraving" width="26" height="auto" src="' + source + '" /></span>');

            text_remaining = text_max - iCnt;

            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
        } else {
            $("#errors").append('<label>Reached the limit</label><br>');
        }


    });

    // REMOVE ONE ELEMENT PER CLICK.
    $('#btn2').click(function() {
        if (iCnt != 0) {
            $('#tb' + iCnt).remove();
            iCnt = iCnt - 1;
            text_remaining = text_max - iCnt;
            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
        }

        if (iCnt == 0) {
            $("#errors").append('<label>Please add characters.</label><br>');
        }
    });

    $("#btn3").click(function() {
        $("#FrontFace").empty();
        $("#errors").empty();
        if (iCnt != 0) {
            iCnt = 0;
            text_remaining = 70;
            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
        }
    });


    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action'),
            method = $(this).attr('method'),
            data = [];

        $(this).find('span.input').each(function(index, value) {
            var type = $(this).data('type')
            data.push(type);
        });
        console.log(data);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wasg1t99/7/)

**Another way** to do this, without having to loop through elements to gather data, is adding a hidden `<input>` field which would be sent with the submit of the form.

This would result in a `$_POST['character']` array being sent with the form

```
$('img').click(function() {
    if (iCnt <= 70) {
        var source = $(this).attr("src");
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        iCnt = iCnt + 1;
        $("#errors").empty();
        $("#FrontFace").append('<span class="input" id="tb' + iCnt + '">'
             +'<img alt="faller-kryptos-engraving" width="26" height="auto" src="' + source + '" />'
             +'<input type="hidden" name="characters[]" value="' + type + '"/>'
             +'</span>');

        text_remaining = text_max - iCnt;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    } else {
        $("#errors").append('<label>Reached the limit</label><br>');
    }


});
```

This would result in a `$_POST['character']` array being sent with the form, and you could read it with

```
foreach($_POST['character'] AS $index=>$char){
    ....
}
```

Comment: I did not understand a single word... Please use some punctuation and also update your post giving the right context

Comment: Thanks your example works perfectly. I was searching for the name attribute because the full form is a multistep form and there are a number of other form input fields, radio buttons etc. I had provided a full example that showed this when I first created the question but somone commented and told me to shorten my example

Comment: could you show me how to send your hidden input field example as an email in php?

Comment: Hidden input field will be sent together with the form to `contact.php`, then you create the content and send the mail. I'm not going to show you how, there are lots of demo and tutorials online...it's an easy task

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it was really appreciated.